# Possible to export a Blue Prism process into an exe file?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

It is possible to export a blue prism process into an exe file so that someone without the blue prism software be able to run it? This works with macro scheduler, just wondering if it is the same in blue prism. Thanks in advance

Comment: BluePrism (the company) issues paid licences. Don't you think what you're asking would not be easily accessible to the public and that BluePrism (the company) would do what they can to make it not work if it did work?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. the software is not self running, a blue prism process can only be ran by bleuprism software. trying to do it otherwise would circumvent the set up of how the blueprism company operates.